# Using MySQL Workbench to connect to MySQL on Linux server

Tags: networking, server, mysql, mysql-workbench

I am not new to Linux, but am "retooling" and getting back into the LAMP model and working to get everything configured and setup for my environment.

I am currently in the process of completing the installation and configuration of Ubuntu 16.04 (and MySQL 5.7)

I have installed  MySQL Workbench v 6.3 on a local windows 10 box while Linux running on a remote box and MySQL on the same box as the remote.  This is all taking place within the same firewall so I am not sending traffic outside of the firewall.

The problem is when I try to connect to the MySQL server from Workbench, I get the error message “Failed to Coinnect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with root user.

**Things that have been checked**

- I can connect to MySQL while in an SSH session using Putty from the Windows 10 box and look at the tables that were setup during the MySQL install.
- I was able to create user accounts while in MySQL.  So, I know MySQL is running.
- I can ping 127.0.0.1 in the SSH session and I get confirmation the ping arrived at the address provided.
- I have checked the mysqld.cnf in the /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/ directory for the bind-address which is  =  127.0.0.1.

So, any help anyone can provide for resolution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have MySQL listen on an interface that the other PC can access.

At the moment it is only listening on `127.0.0.1`, which is the interface only the local machine and clients over SSH can access

If you set it to `0.0.0.0` it will listen on all interfaces instead, so the other machine will be able to connect to it, assuming the machine firewalls are configured correctly.

Comment: i have updated the ip address and set it to 0.0.0.0 and checked the status of the firewall.  On the Lunix box the status shows inactive after I ran the sudo ufw status and on the Windows box I turned the firewall off (I know this is not the smartest thing, but using process of elimination I am hoping I will have success connecting).  However, this still will not allow a connection from MySQL workbench.

Comment: I have now installed mysql-workbench on the Linux box that is running mysql and was able to connect to mysql and start to create schemas, tables etc...  As I stated in my previous post I have taken the firewalls out of the equation but still not joy.  Any suggestions as to how to fix the issue of connecting from a remote box would be appreciated.